# Increase a value type from multiple async methods (i.e. threads) in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I need to increase a counter from multiple threads (async methods) in C#.

- I cannot pass a ref parameter because it's an async method
- I cannot just update the value (or lock on it) because it's a value type
- I cannot use Interlocked because I can't put a ref to the counter in the async method

So the only thing I'm coming up with is to make something silly like a `List<int>` and put my `int` in there so threads can lock on the List and update the value.

I'm hoping that's a known use case and there's a more elegant way of doing it?

Here's a small example, never mind small syntax issues:

```
public void DoStuff()
{
    int counter;
    var tasks = new List<Task>()
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        tasks.Add(AsyncMethod(<SOMETHING>));
    }
    Task.WaitAll(tasks);
    Console.WriteLine("Total: {0}", counter);
 }

 public async Task AsyncMethod(<SOMETHING>)
 {
     // Lock if needed by <SOMETHING>
     <SOMETHING>+=20;
 }
```

Do I need to create a class with an `int` field, or does C# provide something off-the-box? I'm not stuck on this, just trying to learn in hindsight if there was a better way. Thanks!

FOR FUTURE VISITORS:
The consensus seems to be to create a custom class such as `class IntHolder { public int Value {get;set;}}` that can be passed by reference and locked on (or use Interlocked on)

Thanks a lot all!

Comment: Can you please show us a simple yet complete reproduce of your problem? [This](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#f:r/K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcAoUlaIoYB0AKgBYBOqAhgCb5k0gDWIOe08Sa6ZVtBtBzYADsABGAGzABjGLKnMQMAMIwA3thg6Y46XJjMEEeaWYsYAWQAUASk3bdzyMhhgYAXhgAGHM+caAHcaMDdzVmIATTBUKTp7fwCdAEkINEopAHtZFlQ6YjTZanRUdJtqADN3OySdAF9seqAA=) works fine.

Comment: What's the problem to use wrapper class for this purpose? Just make a class with the only one `int` field.

Comment: I seem to recall that the .net framework had specific classes designed for just what you are describing. Maybe in the Task Parallel Library? Alternatively, you can lock on an instance of Object. As @AndreyNasonov commented, you could implement that inside a wrapper class.

Comment: Thanks guys. @YuvalItzchakov I've added some code example to illustrate the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can using `lock` on any object, not just the object that you want to use.

For example:

```
object locking_object = new object();
```

This creates an object that will be used only for locking.

And then later, when you want to increment the value:

```
lock(locking_object)
{
    integer++;
}
```

**Update based on the comments:**

Create a class to hold the integer value like this:

```
class IntHolder
{
    public int Value;
}
```

You can use the `Interlocked` class to do something like this:

```
Interlocked.Increment(ref int_holder.Value);
```

Where `int_holder` is the name of the variable of type `IntHolder` that you pass to your method.

Comment: the integer is a value type. How would I get it into the async method that increases in a way that modifies the original value, if I can't use `ref`?

Comment: @Miquel You will obviously need to be able to access the `int` from all threads. Either by making it a member of a class accessible to all of them, or wrapping it with a `IntHolder` class and pass the reference to the class instance to all threads.

Comment: Actually, when you do that, it would be better in terms of performance to use the `Interlocked` class instead of using `lock`

Comment: @YoryeNathan an `IntHolder` sounds like a purpose made class for this, is it a C# class though?

Comment: @YacoubMassad won't I be needing to pass the variable as `ref` in order to use `Interlocked`? Passing a ref won't work on async.

Comment: I was adding on what @Miquel said, once you use `IntHolder`, then you can use `Interlocked.Increment(ref ref_holder.Value);` Or if you make the integer a field, then you can use `Interlocked.Increment(ref m_Integer);`

Comment: Thanks @YacoubMassad Do you have the C# doc for IntHolder? I can't seem to find it, but there is an AsyncLocal that Yuval Itzchakov mentioned in the other answer

Comment: `IntHolder` is your own class. `class IntHolder { public int Value {get;set;}}` The purpose of this is simply to wrap around the value type, so you can pass the whole package as a reference type. You can call it whatever you want.

Comment: I guess Yorye Nathan is talking about a custom class. It would be something like this `class IntHolder { public int Value;}`

Comment: @YoryeNathan right, ok, that makes sense. To be clear, this was about figuring out if there was a built-in way. Defining your own class will certainly solve it too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to flow the value across async methods, perhaps you can take advantage of [`AsyncLocal<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn906268(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
private AsyncLocal<int> counter = new AsyncLocal<int>();
public async Task FooAsync()
{
     await Task.Yield();
     Interlocked.Increment(ref counter.Value);
}
```

Comment: That's cool. Like a built-in wrapper for that purpose exactly. But is there any difference between that and using your own class to wrap around the `int`?

Comment: Yes, the `AsyncLocal<T>` is cool but it does not match the author's needs. The author wants to use a global variable across multiple async methods/threads, but not local value storage.

Comment: @YoryeNathan Change notifications if you use [this constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn906228(v=vs.110).aspx) at the very least. Thanks!

Comment: @Andrey If that field is a class level variable, it should be available across async method calls and flow between them. It won't allocate a new value per call.

Comment: I tried your snippet. It gave me error: "A property or indexer may not be passed as an out or ref parameter"

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd post a full code sample b/c some things can be tricky.

```
    public class MyIntIncrementer
    {
        public int MyInt = 0;
    }

    public static String TimeStamp
    {
        get { return DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff"); } //yyyy-MM-dd
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Task<string>> tasks = new List<Task<string>>();
        int waitSeconds = 5;

        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}: Start", TimeStamp));
        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

        MyIntIncrementer iIncrementer = new MyIntIncrementer();
        iIncrementer.MyInt = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            //definitely loops and changes values - but when passed in to the function they don't remain that way... see iParam
            //Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}: Looping... i: {1}\n", TimeStamp,i));

            tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
            {
                // all have 10 => last value :(
                // Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}: Running... i: {1}\n", TimeStamp, i));

                return SayYesIfEven(waitSeconds, i, iIncrementer);
            }));
        }

        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}: Before Wait...", TimeStamp));

        // wait for them to run
        Task.WhenAll(tasks).Wait();
        //Task.WhenAll(tasks); // doesn't wait with .Wait()

        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}: After Wait... Results:", TimeStamp));

        // get the results
        for (int i = 0; i < tasks.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(tasks[i].Result);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}: Done  ({1}s)", TimeStamp, (DateTime.Now - start).TotalSeconds));
    }

    public static async Task<string> SayYesIfEven(int waitSeconds, int iParam, MyIntIncrementer iIncrementer)
    {
        int localIParamStart = (int)iParam; // no difference from passed in value when copied locally

        int currentIStart = iIncrementer.MyInt; // not guaranteed to be unique

        // iParam is the last value and when 'iIncrementer.MyInt' prints here, it's sometimes the same in multiple threads
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:00}: Before Increment: even? {1} <=> {2:00} / iP: {3:00} / LiP: {4:00} / in.mP: {5:00}", TimeStamp, (currentIStart % 2 == 0 ? "Yes" : "No "), currentIStart, iParam, localIParamStart, iIncrementer.MyInt));

        // best way to get a unique value 
        int currentIR = Interlocked.Increment(ref iIncrementer.MyInt); // all threads wait on a lock to increment and then they move forward with their own values
        int currentI = iIncrementer.MyInt;
        int localIParam = (int)iParam;

        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:00}: After  Increment: even? {1} <=> {2:00} => {6:00} => {7:00} / iP: {3:00} / LiP: {4:00} => {8:00} / in.mP: {5:00}", TimeStamp, (currentI % 2 == 0 ? "Yes" : "No "), currentIStart, iParam, localIParamStart, iIncrementer.MyInt, currentIR, currentI, localIParam));

        await Task.Delay(waitSeconds * 1000); // simulate delay

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            // do other stuff...

            // iParam and iIncrementer.value have the last value (note that this statement runs after the above delay)
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:00}: Inside Run after Delay: even? {1} <=> {2:00} => {6:00} => {7:00} / iP: {3:00} / LiP: {4:00} => {8:00} / in.mP: {5:00}", TimeStamp, (currentI % 2 == 0 ? "Yes" : "No "), currentIStart, iParam, localIParamStart, iIncrementer.MyInt, currentIR, currentI, localIParam));
            return "something";
        });

        // all have last value when showing what was passed into SayYesIfEven - and iIncrementer.value is also the last value
        return (String.Format("{0:00}: Returning: even? {1} <=> {2:00} => {6:00} => {7:00} / iP: {3:00} / LiP: {4:00} => {8:00} / in.mP: {5:00}", TimeStamp, (currentI % 2 == 0 ? "Yes" : "No "), currentIStart, iParam, localIParamStart, iIncrementer.MyInt, currentIR, currentI, localIParam));
    }
```

Output:

```
    13:55:35.340: Start
    13:55:35.357: Before Wait...

    // rearranged to show before/after values side by side
    // note the duplicate values for MyIntIncrementer.MyInt - and last values for iParam

    13:55:35.357: Before Increment: even? Yes <=> 00 / iP: 10 / LiP: 10 / in.mP: 00
    13:55:35.357: Before Increment: even? Yes <=> 00 / iP: 10 / LiP: 10 / in.mP: 00
    13:55:35.371: Before Increment: even? Yes <=> 02 / iP: 10 / LiP: 10 / in.mP: 02
    13:55:35.371: Before Increment: even? No  <=> 03 / iP: 10 / LiP: 10 / in.mP: 03
    13:55:35.371: Before Increment: even? Yes <=> 04 / iP: 10 / LiP: 10 / in.mP: 04
    13:55:35.371: Before Increment: even? No  <=> 05 / iP: 10 / LiP: 10 / in.mP: 05
    13:55:35.371: Before Increment: even? Yes <=> 06 / iP: 10 / LiP: 10 / in.mP: 06
    13:55:35.371: Before Increment: even? No  <=> 07 / iP: 10 / LiP: 10 / in.mP: 07
    13:55:35.371: Before Increment: even? No  <=> 07 / iP: 10 / LiP: 10 / in.mP: 07
    13:55:35.371: Before Increment: even? Yes <=> 00 / iP: 10 / LiP: 10 / in.mP: 00

    // after the locked increment, notice we have reliable independent values

    13:55:35.371: After  Increment: even? Yes <=> 00 => 02 => 02 / iP: 10 / LiP: 10 => 10 / in.mP: 02
    13:55:35.371: After  Increment: even? No  <=> 00 => 01 => 01 / iP: 10 / LiP: 10 => 10 / in.mP: 01
    13:55:35.371: After  Increment: even? No  <=> 02 => 03 => 03 / iP: 10 / LiP: 10 => 10 / in.mP: 03
    13:55:35.371: After  Increment: even? Yes <=> 03 => 04 => 04 / iP: 10 / LiP: 10 => 10 / in.mP: 04
    13:55:35.371: After  Increment: even? No  <=> 04 => 05 => 05 / iP: 10 / LiP: 10 => 10 / in.mP: 05
    13:55:35.371: After  Increment: even? Yes <=> 05 => 06 => 06 / iP: 10 / LiP: 10 => 10 / in.mP: 06
    13:55:35.371: After  Increment: even? No  <=> 06 => 07 => 07 / iP: 10 / LiP: 10 => 10 / in.mP: 07
    13:55:35.371: After  Increment: even? Yes <=> 07 => 08 => 08 / iP: 10 / LiP: 10 => 10 / in.mP: 08
    13:55:35.371: After  Increment: even? No  <=> 07 => 09 => 09 / iP: 10 / LiP: 10 => 10 / in.mP: 09
    13:55:35.371: After  Increment: even? Yes <=> 00 => 10 => 10 / iP: 10 / LiP: 10 => 10 / in.mP: 10

    13:55:40.381: Inside Run after Delay: even? Yes <=> 07 => 08 => 08 / iP: 10 / LiP: 10 => 10 / in.mP: 10
    13:55:40.381: Inside Run after Delay: even? Yes <=> 05 => 06 => 06 / iP: 10 / LiP: 10 => 10 / in.mP: 10
    13:55:40.381: Inside Run after Delay: even? No  <=> 07 => 09 => 09 / iP: 10 / LiP: 10 => 10 / in.mP: 10
    13:55:40.381: Inside Run after Delay: even? No  <=> 04 => 05 => 05 / iP: 10 / LiP: 10 => 10 / in.mP: 10
    13:55:40.381: Inside Run after Delay: even? No  <=> 02 => 03 => 03 / iP: 10 / LiP: 10 => 10 / in.mP: 10
    13:55:40.381: Inside Run after Delay: even? No  <=> 00 => 01 => 01 / iP: 10 / LiP: 10 => 10 / in.mP: 10
    13:55:40.381: Inside Run after Delay: even? Yes <=> 00 => 10 => 10 / iP: 10 / LiP: 10 => 10 / in.mP: 10
    13:55:40.381: Inside Run after Delay: even? Yes <=> 00 => 02 => 02 / iP: 10 / LiP: 10 => 10 / in.mP: 10
    13:55:40.381: Inside Run after Delay: even? Yes <=> 03 => 04 => 04 / iP: 10 / LiP: 10 => 10 / in.mP: 10
    13:55:40.381: Inside Run after Delay: even? No  <=> 06 => 07 => 07 / iP: 10 / LiP: 10 => 10 / in.mP: 10

    // notice at the bottom of the call - MyIntIncrementer.MyInt is the last value and thus never unique
    // - only the initial value (obtained after the lock and before any delay) is still reliable - same behavior found on a 100+ loop

    13:55:40.381: After Wait... Results:

    13:55:40.381: Returning: even? Yes <=> 00 => 10 => 10 / iP: 10 / LiP: 10 => 10 / in.mP: 10
    13:55:40.381: Returning: even? No  <=> 00 => 01 => 01 / iP: 10 / LiP: 10 => 10 / in.mP: 10
    13:55:40.381: Returning: even? Yes <=> 00 => 02 => 02 / iP: 10 / LiP: 10 => 10 / in.mP: 10
    13:55:40.381: Returning: even? No  <=> 02 => 03 => 03 / iP: 10 / LiP: 10 => 10 / in.mP: 10
    13:55:40.381: Returning: even? Yes <=> 03 => 04 => 04 / iP: 10 / LiP: 10 => 10 / in.mP: 10
    13:55:40.381: Returning: even? No  <=> 04 => 05 => 05 / iP: 10 / LiP: 10 => 10 / in.mP: 10
    13:55:40.381: Returning: even? Yes <=> 05 => 06 => 06 / iP: 10 / LiP: 10 => 10 / in.mP: 10
    13:55:40.381: Returning: even? No  <=> 06 => 07 => 07 / iP: 10 / LiP: 10 => 10 / in.mP: 10
    13:55:40.381: Returning: even? Yes <=> 07 => 08 => 08 / iP: 10 / LiP: 10 => 10 / in.mP: 10
    13:55:40.381: Returning: even? No  <=> 07 => 09 => 09 / iP: 10 / LiP: 10 => 10 / in.mP: 10

    13:55:40.381: Done  (5.0410934s)
```